# Problem using mod_deflate with ProxyPass

Tags: apache, proxy, gzip

Using Apache 2.0 (2.0.53) on a particular legacy system, enabling mod_deflate causes directly-served content to be gzip-encoded just fine. However, and this is my problem, content proxied from another server using ProxyPass is not getting gzip-encoded. Wireshark shows me there is no encoding header in the response and the body is in plain text.

I have another similar system, also running Apache 2.0 (2.0.52), where the proxied content IS being gzipped, and I can't find any significant difference between the configuration of the two systems.

Details:
mod_deflate is being enabled using a file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/deflate.conf` containing:

```
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/xml text/css text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json
</ifModule>
```

The proxying is being done within the `<VirtualHost>` section using these lines:

```
ProxyPass /mtserver http://localhost:8000
ProxyPassReverse /mtserver http://localhost:8000
```

Can anyone point me at a possible reason for one system not compressing the proxied content?

Comment: To clarify, if you directly query the origin server the content is compressed?

Comment: No, the origin server on localhost:8000 always supplies uncompressed. On most of my systems Apache then compresses it for me, but I can't work out why on this one system it doesn't.

Comment: Unless you have configured your proxy to do compression, it will simply pass through what your backend is doing.  Likely the other backend is serving both compressed and uncompressed content. You should either disable all compression on the backends and handle it at the proxy layer or manage compression on the backend and just let the proxy work transparently.

Comment: The backend server is my own code (adapted from a lightweight http server), and has no compression built in. As I said, on most of my similar systems, Apache is compressing the stream fine. I just can't work out what's different on this one system - I've compared the httpd config files in detail.

Comment: That is my point -- your proxy is not doing the compression.  It is just forwarding content.  Since your backend content is not compressed, then your proxied content will not be either unless specifically configure the proxy to handle the compression.

Comment: Sorry, I'm evidently not explaining well. In my original question, I listed what I have included in a `deflate.conf`, which therefore applies to the whole Apache server. This specifies compression of the content types listed. On most of my systems, this is sufficient to tell Apache to compress both locally-served content and proxied content. I have used Wireshark to verify it is actually doing this. On this _one_ system, I can't see anything I have done differently, but it is only compressing locally-served content, not proxied content. That is what puzzles me. The backend is the same on both.

Comment: From your question it is not clear what configurations are on what server or where compression is intended to be done.  I recommend you edit your question to make this clearer.

Comment: Are you sure the `Content-Type` header is correctly set? As `mod_deflate` would operate on its value, so if it is missing or invalid or another value than those on the list, nothing will work as intended.